# Facebook OAuth Error: Application request limit reached

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to get facebook's example page working (again) which you can find [here](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk). I'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#4) Application request limit reached thrown in C:\wamp\www\base_facebook.php on line 988
```

I've googled this and the problem seems to be easily fixed by using the steps outlined [here](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=95309). However, when I go to facebook.com/insights, my application isn't listed (I am logged in).

The weirder part is that when I go to my app via Developers > My apps, I can go to the page of my app and click "Insights". This brings me to the Insights page for my app... but the diagnostic section is nowhere to be found. Can anyone help?

Comment: Let's read below article
[Facebook Application Request limit reached][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272391/facebook-application-request-limit-reached

Comment: Can u check json is enabled on your wamp server

Answer (score 8):

The outlined way of finding out why this happens is:

1. Log into https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
2. The last app you've edited should already be loaded on the right side; if not, find your app on the left side and click the name.
3. Scroll down until you see the `Insights` section and click `See All`.
4. From the menu on the left side, select `API > Activity & Errors`.

Comment: What if you are using graph.facebook.com/?id=<url> ?

Answer (score 4):

The [Facebook "Graph API Rate Limiting" docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/api-rate-limiting) says that an error with code `#4` is an [app level rate limit](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/api-rate-limiting#applimit), which is different than [user level rate limits](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/api-rate-limiting#userlimit). Although it doesn't give any exact numbers, it describes their app level rate-limit as:

> This rate limiting is applied globally at the app level. Ads api calls are excluded.
>
> - Rate limiting happens real time on sliding window for past one hour.
> - Stats is collected for number of calls and queries made, cpu time spent, memory used for each app.
> - There is a limit for each resource multiplied by monthly active users of a given app.
> - When the app uses more than its allowed resources the error is thrown.
> - Error, Code: 4, Message: Application request limit reached

The docs also give recommendations for avoiding the rate limits. For app level limits, they are:

> Recommendations:
>
> - Verify the error code (4) to confirm the throttling type.
> - Do not make burst of calls, spread out the calls throughout the day.
> - Do smart fetching of data (important data, non duplicated data, etc).
>
>   - Real-time insights, make sure API calls are structured in a way that you can read insights for as many as Page posts as possible, with minimum number of requests.
>   - Don't fetch users feed twice (in the case that two App users have a specific friend in common)
>   - Don't fetch all user's friends feed in a row if the number of friends is more than 250. Separate the fetches over different days. As an option, fetch first the app user's news feed (me/home) in order to detect which friends are more important to the App user. Then, fetch those friends feeds first.
> - Consider to limit/filter the requests by using the following parameters: "since", "until", "limit"
> - [For page related calls use realtime updates to subscribe to changes in data.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/)
> - [Field expansion allows ton "join" multiple graph queries into a single call.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/)
> - [Etags to check if the data querying has changed since the last check.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/etags-reference/)
> - For page management developers who does not have massive user base, have the admins of the page to accept the app to increase the number of users.

Finally, the docs give the following informational tips:

> - Batching calls will not reduce the number of api calls.
> - Making parallel calls will not reduce the number of api calls.

Comment: Hey thanks for adding this to my question even though it's 3 years old. Unsure if this answers my question but I hope it helps someone in the future

Comment: @tnw Me too! I am debugging the same problem (error code `#4`) right now and I got mis-lead by many other sources saying the limit was "600 calls per 600 seconds". That may be true but I believe it only applies to user access-tokens, not app-level tokens.

Answer (score 2):

If you make a GET request to one of FB graph API endpoints that does not require access_token that does not mean you should not include it in request parameter. If you do as FB documentation says as do not include access_token than in FB server side it registers into your server machine. So limit (whatever amount is it exactly) can be reached very easily. If you however, put the user access token into the request (&access_token=XXXXXX) then requests register into the specific user, so the limit hardly ever be reached. You can test it with a simple script that makes 1000 requests with and without user access_token.

NOTE, FB app access token will not be sufficient as you will face the same problem: requests will be registered into app access_token that situation is alike making requests without access_token.