# fql query limit?

Tags: facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

What is the daily limit for a user/website to fql multiquery facebook? I am building a website that queries a lot of facebook data for the user each time they log in? I wanted to know how many times our website can do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar thread that talks about this issue here:

[Facebook Application limit reached when calling FQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759562/facebook-application-limit-reached-when-calling-fql)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: but is it possible to do what Klout.com do but in real-time? Or will you reach a query limit?

Comment: I do not have idea about Klout.com.This is happening because it is polling.so they have mentioned an alternative solution.