# Facebook Application Request limit reached

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting an FBerror "This operation can't be completed: Application request limit reached".
Does anybody know why is it so? How to check the limit? How to increase the limit? What depends on the limit allocation?

Comment: if you are adding test users to FB using a application , there is a limit of adding it , you need to delete it first , to move on again    https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

Comment: No test user. The error occurred while calling graph api.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook OAuth Error: Application request limit reached](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6412232/facebook-oauth-error-application-request-limit-reached)

Comment: Yeah, looks like a dupe question.

Comment: Facebook has some [documentation about its API rate limiting](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/api-rate-limiting) although it doesn't provide any exact numbers as to what the limits are. We need to know which error code you are getting in the FBerror, i.e. #4 is a app-level limit.

Comment: For those who have just come here from Googling this error: **Stack Overflow is a programming website, we are not Facebook's forum. If you have concerns about this issue, please ask it over on the [Facebook Help Community](https://www.facebook.com/help/community) instead.**

Answer (score 34):

I recently ran across this issue doing a large number of requests using an application access token (the initial project requirements mandated that the user shouldn't have to authorize the app).

After much frustration, we finally were put in touch with a contact at Facebook who provided the following info in response to my question regarding request limits:

> There is a limit, but it's pretty high, it should be difficult to hit unless they're using the same access tokens for all calls and not caching results, etc. **It's 600 calls per 600 seconds per access token.**

Ultimately we ended up requiring the user to authorize, as Facebook does not seem to distinguish between user access tokens (one token per user) and application access tokens (one token for all users) when calculating its seemingly arbitrary request limits.

If you are running into this error with a user access token, you may need to optimize your API calls (possibly by combining FQL queries or replacing multiple Graph requests with a single FQL query).

Comment: I have found [a different source](http://www.quora.com/Whats-the-Facebook-Open-Graph-API-rate-limit) that indicates the rate limit above only applies to user access tokens. It says the rate limit for application access-tokens is **100M calls per 24 hours per app**.

Answer (score -8):

try this with your php code:

50 continuous FQL calls. After a pause of 10 seconds (sleep (10)) You repeat.

```
if($nr%50==0)
{
   sleep(10);
   echo "\n\n---Bloque #".++$numBloque."---\n\n";
 }
```