# Application request limit reached for facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I got this error for some reason:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#4) Application request limit reached", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 4
  }
}
```

From my investigation, daily request limit seem to be 100m requests. The Insights -> Developer -> Activity and Errors does not update in realtime (lagging by 4 days), there isn't any restrictions/throttling/errors to speak of. The highest request rate I had was on 21st, and it is 500k and I don't think i got any request limits reached errors (error highest was 1000 errors that day).

Any idea what I could be doing to resolve this? Or at least find out what limits are to my app?

Comment: +1 for having a website that can hit the limit.

Answer (score 2):

I have same error.
I think there is a facebook bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/442544732471951?browse=search_50bc5133cf13d5c74557627

Please subscribe to this error to solve it quickly...

Answer (score 1):

Quote from here: [Facebook Application Request limit reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272391/facebook-application-request-limit-reached)

> There is a limit, but it's pretty high, it should be difficult to hit unless they're using the same access tokens for all calls and not caching results, etc. **It's 600 calls per 600 seconds per access token.**