# FQL Application Limit Error

Tags: facebook, request, limit, facebook-fql

I'm working on a WordPress blog and am trying to show the total_count from Facebook FQL for the URL of each post. So when I go into a post, I grab the URL generated by WordPress, and then run the following FQL:

```
$fqlQuery = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20like_count,%20share_count,%20total_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%22" . $url . "%22&format=json";
```

Just moved to the live server today, and this FQL is now returning the following in the JSON:

```
["error_code"]=> int(4) ["error_msg"]=> string(33) "Application request limit reached"
```

What is the request limit? How is that number determined? For instance, if I run that same FQL on my development box, I have no trouble at all. Our dev server, no issues.

Comment: Running into the same issue as of recent.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from here: [Facebook Application Request limit reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272391/facebook-application-request-limit-reached)

> There is a limit, but it's pretty high, it should be difficult to hit unless they're using the same access tokens for all calls and not caching results, etc. **It's 600 calls per 600 seconds per access token.**

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for your case, this is not an Application Request limit.
As soon as a request is performed on server-side, facebook needs an ACCESS TOKEN  within your URL requests (as a parameter).
This avoids bot massive requests.

If the ACCESS TOKEN is not provided, facebook servers will deny your request with the error you talked about (33 or 4, which is the Application Request limit).

**To get your ACCESS TOKEN** (so your key), you just have to connect to facebook with your account, which must be declared as a developper account.

Then, go to the [API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.2), where you'll get your ACCESS TOKEN.

From the API explorer, you'll be able to elaborate the requests you want, which will work well triggered from your live server.