# Graph API Error - (#4) Application request limit reached

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I'm using Batch requests to execute an FQL queries on the Stream table.
The queries retrieve posts from the past few days for all the app user's friends.
My application executes about 150K Graph API requests per day (30K each time), but no more that 600 requests in 600 seconds per access token (As Facebook limits the stream API). 
I sometime receive the following error: (#4) Application request limit reached.

Is there a known limit for Graph API requests per 24 hours / 1 hour ?

Comment: There are only 86,400 seconds in a day -- how do you execute 150,000 graph api requests in a day without exceding 1 per sec?

Comment: I don't exceed the request per second limit for each **Access token**. Not for all the application requests

Comment: @MustiRabin did you ever get an answer for this elsewhere? I'm also experiencing this issue. Is there an additional undocumented limit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook OAuth Error: Application request limit reached](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412232/facebook-oauth-error-application-request-limit-reached)

Comment: The [FB rate limiting docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/api-rate-limiting) are helpful but don't provide exact numbers as to what their limits are. You seem to be hitting a app-level limit based on the fact you are seeing an error code #4.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is 600 request / 600 seconds but not 86400 request per day... it seams that the "600s" is a sliding time period (not really documented), so may be you go over this limit for small time periods?

Another intersting point is that this limit is per 600 seconds, per Token **and per IP...**