# All API calls returns "Application limits reached"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, blocking, limits

Using my application is not possible since every Graph API call returns:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#4) Application request limit reached",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 4
   }
}
```

There is no special traffic peak shown in statistics, or no idea what is causing this? I don't see any limits mentioned anywhere. My users are getting very upset since this affects to all users. What are the limits then? How those can be extended?

And every user of my app is getting this error. So my email is now flooded of error messages from angry users.

Any idea what I can do? Or when this limit is reset?

Comment: How intensively are you querying their API?

Comment: you can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412232/facebook-oauth-error-application-request-limit-reached

Comment: Well there's 40k daily users. And daily API calls have been around10-15 million daily api calls for a long time.

Comment: HungryCoder, that doesn't tell any answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seemd to be a case that someone flooded my graph api calls with billion calls a day.