# Application Request Limit issue (Occuring Random with Random Scenarios)

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-android-sdk

I have tried raising this concern on Facebook/Support/Bugs but they said I should post implementation issues here. I have read it everywhere and it seems to be quiet open issue till now. I am not sure, If this will be solved or not.

So, what we are doing is, we have clients - Android and iOS.

Apps on Android/iOS allows users to login into the app and generate the token on the basis of permissions set we have, and we are passing this token to server for fetching further data as and when required for client. As our userbase is increasing we are getting Application request limit reached quiet often.

We are fetching photos of users and their friends using FQL. So, when parallely fetching photos for around 8-10 different users, we are reaching the Application request limit sometimes, which is quiet random and we are not aware of the actual scenario when it breaks up and how. According to facebook the limit, which is 1M calls per day, but we are hitting around 80K - 1 Lac API calls in a day, but as users are increasing it is stretching a bit further, Less than or equal to 200 approax calls/user. We tried doing batch calls as well and we hit the application request limit as well.

If anyone of you could help us understand the complete concept of API limit and how this can be handled, then we will really appreciate the help. We want to understand how API limit is decided and it's rate is calculated over which interval so that we will be able to configure on our side accordingly.

Earlier in the day, we ran into a unique API call issue. Our server started to break for API calls for user tokens that are with us, we (on our systems, other than server) tried fetching the data for those tokens (Simple calls - /me or /me/home), and it was working alright for us but not for server, then we tried setting up another server and redirected the requests to our new server then this server works well for the same set of users. Not sure, what went wrong in this case and how it breaks up. Please help.

Many Thanks,

Reno Jones

Comment: I think a limit is applied to API calls from the same IP as well. And there's questions about that here already, f.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713241/whats-the-facebooks-graph-api-call-limit or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14092989/facebook-api-4-application-request-limit-reached

Comment: Yeah, I have checked out these threads and was of no major help. We are not hitting > 600 calls for a token from a single IP. But yes, We are hitting max of 200 calls / token from a single IP.

Comment: The '1M calls per day' thing is a limit above which you need to have contracts signed, it's not related to the limits on calls per user or on CPU utilisation - those are dynamic, scale with the number of users you have, and are shown in app insights as Mike said in his answer below

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the Insights -> Developer section of developer.facebook.com for your app?

This will show you a breakdown per api call, including warnings and ones that are currently being throttled and why.

Also, are you sure you're using User token authorization and not just your App token?

Beyond that, we take the information from Insights to find api calls to cache on our side rather than hitting Facebook every time. You will likely have to do something similar if you're not already. They have limits for calling too often, as well as for requesting too much data. For those, we had to reduce the limits of historical data we requested.